# VS Code and Julia - Unable to run Julia applications via CTRL+F5

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I'm trying to get the Julia extension working in VS code. I can run Julia files via the REPL and I can debug Julia files in a new process. ***However I cannot run Julia files in a new process***. In other words, whilst all other run options work, the circled option in the image below does not.

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

I am using the newest stable version of Julia (1.7.3), and VS code is fully updated. I am using version 1.6.28 of the Julia VS code extension. I am also using Windows 10. When using CRTL+F5 I get no feedback from VS code at all. Whilst a counter does appear in the Run and Debug pane, the runtime instance isn't displayed in the call stack until I run the file another way. For example, if I launch VS code and run a Julia file with "Run File in New Process" the run and debug pane looks as follows:

[image]

If I then run the same program again with "Debug File in New Process", the Run and Debug pane updates as follows:

[image]

The only other weird behaviour I notice is when the Julia Language Server loads. I get the following output in the Julia Language Server:

```
[ Info: Starting the Julia Language Server
[ Info: Symbol server store is at 'c:\Users\Nick-PC\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\julialang.language-julia\symbolstorev5'.
[ Info: Starting LS at 1659719702
[ Info: Downloading caches...
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Dates.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/D/Dates_ade2ca70-3891-5945-98fb-dc099432e06a/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (4%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for TOML.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/T/TOML_fa267f1f-6049-4f14-aa54-33bafae1ed76/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (8%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for LibCURL.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/L/LibCURL_b27032c2-a3e7-50c8-80cd-2d36dbcbfd21/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (12%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Mmap.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/M/Mmap_a63ad114-7e13-5084-954f-fe012c677804/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (15%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Markdown.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/M/Markdown_d6f4376e-aef5-505a-96c1-9c027394607a/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (19%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for LibGit2.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/L/LibGit2_76f85450-5226-5b5a-8eaa-529ad045b433/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (23%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Logging.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/L/Logging_56ddb016-857b-54e1-b83d-db4d58db5568/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (27%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Base64.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/B/Base64_2a0f44e3-6c83-55bd-87e4-b1978d98bd5f/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (31%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for REPL.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/R/REPL_3fa0cd96-eef1-5676-8a61-b3b8758bbffb/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (35%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Downloads.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/D/Downloads_f43a241f-c20a-4ad4-852c-f6b1247861c6/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (38%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for ArgTools.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/A/ArgTools_0dad84c5-d112-42e6-8d28-ef12dabb789f/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (42%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Random.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/R/Random_9a3f8284-a2c9-5f02-9a11-845980a1fd5c/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (46%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for UUIDs.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/U/UUIDs_cf7118a7-6976-5b1a-9a39-7adc72f591a4/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (50%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Artifacts.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/A/Artifacts_56f22d72-fd6d-98f1-02f0-08ddc0907c33/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (54%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Unicode.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/U/Unicode_4ec0a83e-493e-50e2-b9ac-8f72acf5a8f5/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (58%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Pkg.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/P/Pkg_44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (62%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for InteractiveUtils.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/I/InteractiveUtils_b77e0a4c-d291-57a0-90e8-8db25a27a240/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (65%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Sockets.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/S/Sockets_6462fe0b-24de-5631-8697-dd941f90decc/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (69%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Serialization.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/S/Serialization_9e88b42a-f829-5b0c-bbe9-9e923198166b/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (73%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Tar.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/T/Tar_a4e569a6-e804-4fa4-b0f3-eef7a1d5b13e/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (77%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for NetworkOptions.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/N/NetworkOptions_ca575930-c2e3-43a9-ace4-1e988b2c1908/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (81%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Test.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/T/Test_8dfed614-e22c-5e08-85e1-65c5234f0b40/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (85%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Printf.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/P/Printf_de0858da-6303-5e67-8744-51eddeeeb8d7/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (88%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for SHA.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/S/SHA_ea8e919c-243c-51af-8825-aaa63cd721ce/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (92%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for Libdl.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/L/Libdl_8f399da3-3557-5675-b5ff-fb832c97cbdb/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: Downloading caches... (96%)
┌ Info: Couldn't retrieve cache file for FileWatching.
└   exception = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found while requesting https://www.julia-vscode.org/symbolcache/store/v1/packages/F/FileWatching_7b1f6079-737a-58dc-b8bc-7a2ca5c1b5ee/vnothing_nothing.tar.gz
[ Info: All cache files downloaded. (100%)
[ Info: Loading IJulia from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: Pkg not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Test not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Random not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Libdl not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: UUIDs not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading SoftGlobalScope from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: REPL not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading Conda from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: Downloads not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading JSON from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: Dates not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading Parsers from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: Mmap not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Unicode not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading VersionParsing from cache... (0%)
[ Info: Loading ZMQ from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: Sockets not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: FileWatching not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: ZeroMQ_jll not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Base64 not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Loading MbedTLS from cache... (0%)
┌ Warning: MbedTLS_jll not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: MozillaCACerts_jll not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: InteractiveUtils not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Printf not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
┌ Warning: Markdown not stored on disc
└ @ SymbolServer c:\Users\Nick-PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.28\scripts\packages\SymbolServer\src\SymbolServer.jl:247
[ Info: Received new data from Julia Symbol Server.
```

I also get the following output in "Tasks" after using "Debug File in New Process":

```
Error: there is no registered task type 'julia-proc'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
```

I don't get the same output in "Tasks" if one of the other two run commands is used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. I resolved it by opening a new bash terminal tab, running `import Pkg;` and then `Pkg.add("DynamicalSystems")` in a julia REPL, and adding a Configuration in VS Code to 'Run active Julia file'. I believe you need to run `Pkg.add(<insert package name in quotes>)` for all of the dependencies for the particular file you're trying to run.